# How to prevent eclipse's built-in compiler from executing while an ant-build is running?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I have an ant scripts that re-compiles 20+ schema files into Java classes using JAXB.

Again and again this scripts reports compile errors that read "unable to replace previous version of (some Java file name here)". Apparently some process is holding files open that JAXB is recompiling and after some testing I found out that this process is actually the incremental Java compiler built into eclipse's PDE.

The reason seems to be, that all the schemas include a common schema file that defines some basic types that are used all over the places. The corresponding Java files are thus recreated each time when a schema is compiled that imports that common file.

If I wait for 5 seconds after each recompilation things work fine (because by then the compiler has recompiled and released all newly created Java files). But that makes my ant-script run terribly slow!

Is there some way to hold off the incremental compiler from executing while an Ant script (triggered from within eclipse via "run as... " => "Ant script" ) is running?

Only when ALL schemas have been recompiled it should recompile all the newly generated classes but not during or in parallel with the ant-script's execution!

M.